# oracle apex 18 saml authentication with external identity provider

Tags: saml-2.0, oracle-apex-18.2

I am figuring out the way to use a third party identity provider for apex SSO authentication. Almost i am done with help of [SAML SSO](http://%20%20[1]:%20https://insum.ca/saml2-single-sign-on-with-oracle-application-express/)

Here is my metadata file by identity provider

```
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" ID="u2ecyBkedSUsxVldsmYW27kONOp" cacheDuration="PT1440M" entityID="ps.trivadis.com">
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
<ds:Reference URI="#u2ecyBkedSUsxVldsmYW27kONOp">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<ds:DigestValue>Q0tFZzytRiz4POfzapmQCAOYMGdQ4s62D8U2K7YMP4Y=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>
F+/8hUvaF+gqud3lt6Ua2BIPcrgdlMyMlghBwQ56yy0mcYv7fkxYlDys/8Ae7Lc6o05aGWesg0/m AeyJXZRwDOjuoeNPKvEK63J2xcPpJthN2XVyVdnfb5owAUuwSjysvMFLl8PQyN2Zoe6iOPXsPEJD PTQ7L2JRcM+WkgPGqxa/I8A4A+odK7BLSy4yVIzkrV3XD7NnQ0uiy7BbyFsPla+LGY08mwwAQhT9 Fe5Om4dWduckDP01JO8PJmdbELwkI5XmtQEsZoPbJsZ4AcjNJjX+5Uzm+CQep1BaxtU7xWisHrhh qd2JC76CJX5FMuyAnCaSqY5WHdBZ9CS0RaA5Fg==
</ds:SignatureValue>
</ds:Signature>
<md:IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" WantAuthnRequestsSigned="false">
<md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>
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
</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</md:KeyDescriptor>
<md:NameIDFormat>
urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified
</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://fs.trivadis.com/idp/SSO.saml2"/>
<md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://fs.trivadis.com/idp/SSO.saml2"/>
<saml:Attribute xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Name="mail" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"/>
<saml:Attribute xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Name="givenName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"/>
<saml:Attribute xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Name="sn" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"/>
<saml:Attribute xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Name="memberOf" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"/>
<saml:Attribute xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Name="userPrincipalName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"/>
<saml:Attribute xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Name="SAML_NAME_FORMAT" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified"/>
</md:IDPSSODescriptor>
<md:ContactPerson contactType="administrative"/>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

i have follwed the simple steps as mention in the above link . but still i am not succeeded or actually logged into the apex via third party identity provider. Please let me know if you want to know some additional info about this setup i will share.

Answer (score -1):

Your link doesn't work for me...not sure what you're trying to set up.

We have **SAML2 authentication** working with **Apex** via `mod_auth_mellon` for **Apache** (which just went out of support by the creator, but is still in most repos). Set it up to do **SAML2 authentication** and set an **HTTP header** with the username, and have **Apex Authentication** Scheme check the same header to pull in the username. Works well.